# iOS 7: keyboard shows in UIKeyboardAppearanceLight when an app is opening from multitasking screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've noticed an issue with the keyboard in ios 7, and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

Here's a simple scenario which replicates the issue on a blank xcode 5 project:

When you tap on a textfield added using interface builder (with keyboard appearance set to dark), the correct (dark) keyboard appears.

If you then **resign the responder** (add a button or something for that) > press the home button to get to home screen > double press the homebutton to get to the multitasking selection screen > tap on the app > tap on the textfield > it shows up the **Light** keyboard for a second, and then it draws the dark keyboard.

So is this an iOS bug or could it be something on my end?

Comment: I appreciate that this is quite an old question, but did you ever find a solution? I am seeing similar behavior.

Comment: no solution, I'm certain it's an iOS bug (can't remember what version I was using back then, but it seems that it isn't happening anymore - on iOS8 now)